# how can I echo the content of functions but not its actual return values

Tags: templates, unix, scripting

I'm doing a template script that will create another script in unix. To minimize my code, I'm thinking of re-using the functions of the template script to another script to be created. Below is the customized portion of my script.

```
SCRIPT_LN=script.log
LOG_TMP(){
TMPLTE_LG=`ls -lrt ${SCRIPT_LN}.log | awk -F" " '{print $5}'`
if [ ${TMPLTE_LG} -gt 10000 ]; then
    mv ${SCRIPT_LN}.log ${SCRIPT_LN}.old
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        touch ${SCRIPT_LN}.log
        chmod 777 ${SCRIPT_LN}.log
    else
        echo "Error. Failed to move the log file."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
}

LOG_TMP

cat << SCRIPT_NEW >> script_new.ksh
#!/bin/ksh
#
GET_TIME() {
    SCRIPT_TM=\`date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"\`
}

$(LOG_TMP)
SCRIPT_NEW
```

---

This should be the content of my script_new.ksh after the successful run of the template script.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
GET_TIME() {
    SCRIPT_TM=\`date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"\`
}

LOG_TMP(){
    TMPLTE_LG=`ls -lrt ${SCRIPT_LN}.log | awk -F" " '{print $5}'`
    if [ ${TMPLTE_LG} -gt 10000 ]; then
        mv ${SCRIPT_LN}.log ${SCRIPT_LN}.old
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            touch ${SCRIPT_LN}.log
            chmod 777 ${SCRIPT_LN}.log
        else
            echo "Error. Failed to move the log file."
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
}
```

---

I want the LOG_TMP function to be used by the template script and the new script as well. However, it seems that in my code, it is only working in the template script but was not able to redirect the function into the new script. For the GET_TIME function, I can see it in my new script as it is. Any suggestions on how can I make it?

Comment: `typeset -f GET_TIME`?

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler for replying. Though, I tried the typeset -f command but there is no luck. It only echoed "typeset -f" into script_new.ksh (the one created by the template script). Btw, what I want is the LOG_TMP function to be in my new script, the GET_TIME is being redirected to the new script correctly.

Comment: I replicated the things you've done and I only got "function LOG_TMP" in my alttemp.ksh. Also, when I tried to execute 'man typeset', it says that the manual entry for typeset not found. I'm in AIX server.

Comment: Well, you might have an antique ksh without `typeset -f` support. Lemme go check. Which version of AIX are you running? _[…time…]_  I get what you see on AIX 6.1. The man page on AIX doesn't remind me how to get the ksh version out of it. However, since it doesn't work, you're probably snookered until you get a new ksh installed on the machine.  At the least, there isn't an easy solution. And please note that if you're not on a Linux box, it is often helpful to mention what you're using (it doesn't need to be long: 'Running on AIX 7.1.' would be sufficient) so that people can guess what's up.

Comment: I got this when I executed 'uname -a' command. AIX 1 6 00F613E04C00. I removed the server name, though.

Comment: That was the AIX 6.1 version I tested too.  Sorry, can't help.  The Linux ksh shell was a pdksh (running `echo $KSH_VERSION` yielded
`@(#)PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2`).  That got me a blank line on AIX; I think it is based on ksh88 instead of ksh93, but that's a guess rather than known for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, I believe `typeset -f` is the key to what you want.  Given the input script `script.ksh` like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

LOG_TMP(){
TMPLTE_LG=$(ls -lrt ${SCRIPT_LN}.log | awk -F" " '{print $5}')
if [ ${TMPLTE_LG} -gt 10000 ]; then
    mv ${SCRIPT_LN}.log ${SCRIPT_LN}.old
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        touch ${SCRIPT_LN}.log
        chmod 777 ${SCRIPT_LN}.log
    else
        echo "Error. Failed to move the log file."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
}

{
cat << 'SCRIPT_NEW'
#!/bin/ksh
#
GET_TIME() {
    SCRIPT_TM=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
}

SCRIPT_NEW

typeset -f LOG_TMP
} > script_new.ksh
```

Running the script like this:

```
$ ksh script.ksh
$
```

Leads to the file `script_new.ksh` containing:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
GET_TIME() {
    SCRIPT_TM=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
}

LOG_TMP() {
    TMPLTE_LG=$(ls -lrt ${SCRIPT_LN}.log | awk -F" " '{print $5}')
    if [ ${TMPLTE_LG} -gt 10000 ]
    then
        mv ${SCRIPT_LN}.log ${SCRIPT_LN}.old
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            touch ${SCRIPT_LN}.log
            chmod 777 ${SCRIPT_LN}.log
        else
            echo "Error. Failed to move the log file."
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
}
```

Beware; the output has tabs in it which the input did not, and the formatting assumes tab-stops set at 8.

Note that log files should not be executable; they do not contain programs.  You should seldom make log files publicly writable; they're too important to let just anyone tamper with.  The 0777 permissions are a bad idea, therefore; 0644 or 0664 is more sensible.

I also changed the code to use `$(…)` in place of the obsolescent back-ticks `` `…` ``.  And the best way to ensure that the generated script doesn't execute the commands as it is being created is to enclose the `SCRIPT_NEW` here-doc tag in quotes, as shown.

I also use `{` … `}` as an I/O grouping operation so that there's only one line redirecting material to the output file.  Consequently, I also use the `>` rather than `>>` operator to create the output file.

Comment: You have the output that I want jonathan. However, it seems that we don't have typeset command in AIX. Instead of the whole function LOG_TMP, the one being directed to script_new.ksh is just the word 'function LOG_TMP'

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm in AIX 6.1 and I don't have the typeset command in my server, I decided to use sed command instead. I first included an indicator for the first and last lines of the function that I need to redirect to the new script. Then based on the line numbers (first and last), I've identified correctly the lines to be redirected to the new script.

```
SCRIPT_LN=script.log
# Start of LOG_TMP
LOG_TMP(){
TMPLTE_LG=`ls -lrt ${SCRIPT_LN}.log | awk -F" " '{print $5}'`
if [ ${TMPLTE_LG} -gt 10000 ]; then
    mv ${SCRIPT_LN}.log ${SCRIPT_LN}.old
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        touch ${SCRIPT_LN}.log
        chmod 777 ${SCRIPT_LN}.log
    else
        echo "Error. Failed to move the log file."
        exit 1
    fi
fi
}
# End of LOG_FUNC

LOG_TMP

FUNC_LOGB_TMP=`grep -n "Start of LOG_TMP" ${TMPLTE_BIN_DIR}/${TMPLTE_NAME} | head -1 | awk -F":" '{print $1}'`
FUNC_LOGE_TMP=`grep -n "End of LOG_TMP" ${TMPLTE_BIN_DIR}/${TMPLTE_NAME} | head -1 | awk -F":" '{print $1}'`
FUNC_LOGB=`expr $FUNC_LOGB_TMP + 1`
FUNC_LOGE=`expr $FUNC_LOGE_TMP - 1`

FUNC_LOG() {

sed -n ${FUNC_LOGB},${FUNC_LOGE}p ${TMPLTE_BIN_DIR}/${TMPLTE_NAME}

}

cat << SCRIPT_NEW >> script_new.ksh
#!/bin/ksh
#
GET_TIME() {
    SCRIPT_TM=\`date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"\`
}

$(FUNC_LOG)
SCRIPT_NEW
```